# GNOME 2 + Compiz equivalent?

Tags: upgrade, linux-distributions, window-manager, software-rec, gnome3

Running Fedora 14 and realize I need to either change distros or find an alternative to GNOME 3 in Fedora 17.

Based on what I have read to-date, XFCE and KDE are the go-to WMs if I want to avoid GNOME 3.

I tried KDE 4 and I wasn't impressed; I like the simplicity of GNOME 2 with Compiz and Emerald.

Can't stay on Fedora 14 forever, however, so...where to turn?

Basically looking for these features in my desktop environment:

1. GNOME Do or equivalent
2. Snap to grid/Window tiling
   A must-have, the ability to hot key focused window to a monitor grid region is a huge productivity win.
3. Zoom window to cursor
   In a multi-monitor setup sometimes it's nice to, say, GNOME Do > terminal in one monitor and then hot key the opened window to the other monitor just by zipping the mouse cursor anywhere on target monitor (followed by, of course, snap-to-grid hotkey, all without a single mouse click)
4. Polarization
   At night white background hurts the eyes, so I prefer to hot key polarize to black.
5. Multi-monitor support

I'm partial to Fedora given that I've worked with CentOS for years and have little experience with any other Linux distro; however, if the difference between Fedora and Arch, Mint, etc. is fairly subtle, I'll make the leap, just need a distro & desktop environment that allows me to be productive with keyboard hot keys and provides the above basic features.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MATE](http://mate-desktop.org), a fork of GNOME 2. I assume Compiz would work with it.

> MATE is a fork of Gnome 2.
>   It provides an intuitive and attractive desktop to Linux users using traditional metaphors.

Comment: hmmmmm, nice, looks like one can have their gnome2 + compiz cake and eat it too with MATE: "http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=299"